# Erro ao usar Group by em uma VIEW em Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by

Criei uma VIEW para retornar em uma única consulta os principais dados que preciso.

```sql
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

```sql
VIEW v_historicoProcesso AS
SELECT p.protocolo AS protocolo
      ,p.der AS der
      ,p.data_habilitacao AS dhab
      ,a.descricao AS desandamento u.nome AS nome
      ,ap.bol_ativo AS ativo


  FROM (((processo p JOIN andamento_processo ap
        ON((p.id = ap.id_processo))) JOIN usuario u
        ON((u.id = p.id_usuario))) JOIN andamento a
        ON((ap.id_andamento = a.id)))
 ORDER BY ap.data DESC
```

Até aqui o retorno foi satisfatório. Tendo o resultado algo como:

> 123  2014-04-01 2014-02-02  acordado  simao da silva S
>
> 123  2014-04-01 2014-02-02  acordado  simao da silva N
>
> 123  2014-04-01 2013-02-02  acordado  simao da silva N
>
> 456 2014-04-01 2014-02-02 sem acordo jose da silva N
>
> 456 2014-04-01 2014-02-02 exigencia jose da silva S
>
> 456 2014-04-01 2014-02-02 entrada jose da silva N

Realizei então a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT protocolo
      ,der
      ,dhab
      ,desandamento
      ,nome
  FROM v_historicoprocesso
 WHERE ativo = 'S'
 GROUP BY idprocesso
 ORDER BY der       DESC
         ,protocolo ASC;
```

O Resultado seria apenas os ativos 'S' de cada idProcesso

> 123  2014-04-01 2014-02-02  acordado  simao da silva S
>
> 456 2014-04-01 2014-02-02 exigencia jose da silva S

Tal consulta retornou o seguinte erro:

> **Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'v_historicoProcesso.desAndamento' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

Do que se trata esse erro? E qual seria melhor forma de tratar essa *query*?

Comment: Você está usando `GROUP BY` sem uma [função agregada](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) no `SELECT`.

Comment: mas como resolver?

Comment: Tentou fazer a mesma query sem o `group by`?

Comment: tentei mas nao consegui eliminar a dupliciadade. Se eu remover o campo desAndamento a sql funciona

Comment: Tente `SELECT protocolo, der, dhab, desAndamento ,nome FROM 
 v_historicoProcesso where ativo = 'S' group by protocolo, der, dhab, desAndamento ,nome order by der
 DESC,protocolo ASC;`

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: [DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ambas-as-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre porque a [cláusula group by](http://www.devmedia.com.br/desvendando-a-clausula-group-by-artigo-sql-magazine-47/8082) espera que você esteja agrupando os seus dados.  Por exemplo, se você quisesse agrupar todas as notas de um aluno durante o ano letivo, poderia usa o `group by` para isso.

Exemplo:

```
Select nome, sum (nota) from aluno
Group by nome;
```

Isso faria com que a nota dos alunos fossem somadas e agrupadas de acordo com o nome de cada aluno.

No seu caso, você não está fazendo nenhuma agregação com os restantes das suas colunas. .. **protocolo, der, dhab, desandamento, nome**. ..  Ou você faz alguma agregação (**sum, min, max**,...) ou coloca todas as colunas no **`group by`**.