# DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

## [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

> A instrução SELECT DISTINCT é usada para retornar apenas valores
>   distintos (diferentes).
>
> Dentro de uma tabela, uma coluna geralmente contém muitos valores
>   duplicados; E às vezes você só deseja listar os diferentes valores
>   (distintos).

## **Sintaxe**

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

## [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

> A instrução GROUP BY geralmente é usada com funções agregadas (COUNT,
>   MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) para agrupar o conjunto de resultados por uma ou
>   mais colunas.

## **Sintaxe**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

*`Distinct`* retorna valores diferentes, valores agrupados(*`Group by`*) também ficam distintos(*diferentes*).

Para demonstrar que os mesmo resultados são retornados usando ambas as declarações eu fiz um teste.

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d38e/24)

***Algumas dúvidas:***

Qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações, além da sintaxe? 
Em relação ao desempenho, existem diferenças? Existe alguma possibilidade(*exemplo na prática*) em que o uso das 2 declarações é necessária? 
*Poderiam dar exemplos de uso ideal de cada uma das declarações?*

*Pode parecer bobagem, mas esses tipos de declarações confundem as pessoas e apesar de não parecerem, o uso de ambos trazem resultados iguais.*

Comment: Mas o `group by` permite saber quantos foram agrupados, ou o maior de cada bloco agrupado

Comment: @Isac e em questões de desempenho? Eles também são usados da mesma forma!

Comment: O objetivo de GROUP BY é agrupar linhas que possuam subconjunto semelhante e efetuar funções de agregação nessas linhas. Já o objetivo de DISTINCT é retornar subconjunto de linhas sem repetições.  // Utilizar GROUP BY sem função de agregação gera o mesmo resultado que usar DISTINCT.

Comment: @JoséDiz não quer fazer uma resposta? creio eu que está é uma dúvida corriqueira.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**1. Introdução**

Esclarecer as diferenças e aplicações das duas declarações. A referência é o gerenciador de banco de dados *`SQL Server`*.

---

**2. O que consta na documentação?**

**2.1 DISTINCT**

> ```
> SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]  
> [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] [ WITH TIES ] ]   
> <select_list>  
>
> ALL
> Especifica que linhas duplicadas podem aparecer no conjunto de resultados. 
> ALL é o padrão.
> DISTINCT
> Especifica que só linhas exclusivas podem aparecer no conjunto de resultados. 
> Valores nulos são considerados iguais para os propósitos
> da palavra-chave DISTINCT.
> ```

O par de colchetes no trecho `[ ALL | DISTINCT ]` indica que os dois argumentos são opcionais e que se informados são mutuamente exclusivos, isto é, ou um ou outro. Como consta na documentação o argumento `ALL` é o padrão, ou seja, se nenhum dos argumentos constar do comando, assume-se a presença de `ALL`. A respeito do argumento `DISTINCT` a documentação cita ***linhas exclusivas***, entende-se por valores não repetidos.

A definição de `<select_list>` é extensa mas, para fins deste artigo, somente será considerada a presença de nomes de colunas:

```
SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n
  from tabela;
```

**2.2 GROUP BY**

> ```
> GROUP BY {
>       <column-expression>  
>     | ROLLUP ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
>     | CUBE ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
>     | GROUPING SETS ( <grouping_set> [ ,...n ]  )  
>     | () 
> } [ ,...n ]
> ```

Agrupa um conjunto de linhas selecionadas em um conjunto de linhas de resumo pelos valores de uma ou mais colunas ou expressões. Uma linha é retornada para cada grupo. As funções de agregação na lista de `<seleção>` da cláusula SELECT fornecem informações sobre cada grupo em vez de linhas individuais.

O objetivo dessa cláusula é agrupar linhas em que existam mesmos valores para as colunas definidas na cláusula, gerando subconjuntos. Para cada subconjunto podem então serem executadas funções de agregação nas demais colunas. Ao final, para cada subconjunto é retornada uma única linha, contendo as colunas de agrupamento e os resultados das funções de agregação.
Para a definição de `<column_expression>` iremos considerar somente nomes de colunas.

**2.3 Funções de agregação**

Na documentação de `GROUP BY` consta ***funções de agregação***.
Ao consultar a documentação a respeito de funções de agregação, temos

> As funções de agregação executam um cálculo em um conjunto de valores
> e retornam um único valor. As funções de agregação normalmente são
> usadas com a cláusula `GROUP BY` da instrução SELECT.

Em um modelo simples, as funções de agregação que constem na cláusula SELECT são executadas para cada subconjunto gerado pela cláusula GROUP BY.

Como exemplos de função de agregação temos:

> ```
> COUNT: Retorna o número de itens em um grupo.
> AVG: Retorna a média dos valores em um grupo.
> SUM: Retorna a soma de uma expressão numérica avaliada em um conjunto especificado.
> ```

---

**3. Demonstração de aplicação dos recursos**

Para demonstrar a aplicação de DISTINCT e de GROUP BY, utilizaremos a seguinte tabela:

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE Vendas (
  NomeVendedor varchar(30),
  ProdutoVendido varchar(50),
  QuantidadeVendida integer,
  ValorVenda money
);
```

***INSERT***

```
-- código #2
INSERT into VENDAS values
    ('João', 'Macarrão', 18, 35.00),
    ('Maria', 'Beterraba', 3, 12.00),
    ('José', 'Cenoura', 5, 5.00),
    ('João', 'Molho de tomate', 1, 7.50),
    ('Antônio', 'Beterraba', 4, 16.00),
    ('João', 'Macarrão', 3, 4.20);
```

E você precise gerar os seguintes relatórios:

- Quais são os vendedores?
- Quais produtos cada vendedor vendeu?
- Qual o total de vendas, em reais, de cada vendedor?
- Qual a quantidade de itens vendidos de cada produto, por vendedor?
- Quantos produtos diferentes foram vendidos por cada vendedor?

**3.1 Quais são os vendedores?**

```
-- código #3
SELECT NomeVendedor 
  from VENDAS;

João
Maria
José
João
Antônio
João
```

Entretanto, percebe que o nome **João** aparece 3 vezes. Como eliminar as repetições? É uma aplicação típica do uso de `DISTINCT`!

```
-- código #3a
SELECT DISTINCT NomeVendedor 
  from VENDAS;

Antônio
João
José
Maria
```

Ao analisar os planos de execução dos códigos `#3` e `#3a`, percebe-se facilmente a diferença: A presença do operador lógico `DISTINCT SORT` no plano de execução relativo ao código `#3a`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c0334/1)

**3.2 Quais produtos cada vendedor vendeu?**

Essa requisição envolve o uso de duas colunas: `NomeVendedor` e `ProdutoVendido`.

```
-- código #5
SELECT NomeVendedor, ProdutoVendido 
  from VENDAS;
```

No resultado percebe-se que o par `{João, Macarrão}` aparece mais de uma vez. Eis outra aplicação típica do uso de `DISTINCT`, mas agora atuando sobre duas colunas.

```
-- código #5a
SELECT DISTINCT NomeVendedor, ProdutoVendido 
  from VENDAS;
```

**Importante:** `DISTINCT` atua simultaneamente nas colunas `NomeVendedor` e `ProdutoVendido` . Considera as duas colunas para eliminar as repetições.

**3.3 Qual o total de vendas em reais de cada vendedor?**

Para atender a esta solicitação será necessário somar o conteúdo da coluna `ValorVenda` para cada vendedor. Ou seja, será necessário primeiro separar as vendas por vendedor (gerando um subconjunto com as linhas de cada vendedor) e a seguir realizar a soma de cada subconjunto.

Eis uma aplicação típica da cláusula de agrupamento `GROUP BY`.

Para agrupar as linhas por vendedor utilizamos

```
GROUP BY NomeVendedor
```

E para somar as vendas, utilizamos a função de agregação SUM

```
Sum(ValorVenda)
```

Código

```
-- código #6
SELECT NomeVendedor, SUM(ValorVenda) 
  from Vendas
  group by NomeVendedor;

Antônio 16,00
João 46,70
José 5,00
Maria 12,00
```

Este é o primeiro código deste artigo com a cláusula `GROUP BY`. Analisando o plano de execução do `código #6`, percebe-se algo que não constava nos planos de execução anteriores, que é o operador `Stream Aggregate`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c0334/2/0)

Conforme documentação do operador `Stream aggregate`, *agrupa linhas através de uma ou mais colunas e em seguida calcula uma ou mais expressões de agregação retornadas pela consulta.*

O operador `Stream Aggregate` requer a entrada de dados ordenada pelas colunas dentro de seus grupos. Para garantir essa condição, o otimizador de consultas acrescenta um operador `Sort` antes deste operador (se os dados ainda não estiverem classificados). Isto pode ser observado no plano de execução acima, pois a tabela `Vendas` é do tipo *heap* e sem qualquer índice.

**3.4 Quantos itens de cada produto foram vendidos por vendedor?**

Para atender a essa solicitação será necessário criar subconjuntos por vendedor e dentro de cada um desses subconjuntos, criar subconjuntos por produto. Isto é possível pois a cláusula `GROUP BY` permite a definição de mais de uma coluna.
Para agrupar as linhas por vendedor utilizamos

GROUP BY NomeVendedor

Para agrupar cada produto dentro de cada subconjunto, acrescentamos a coluna que identifica o produto

```
GROUP BY NomeVendedor, ProdutoVendido
```

E para somar a quantidade de itens vendidos utilizamos novamente a função de agregação `SUM`

```
   Sum(QuantidadeVendida)
```

Código:

```
-- código #7
SELECT NomeVendedor, ProdutoVendido, sum (QuantidadeVendida)
  from Vendas
  group by NomeVendedor, ProdutoVendido;

Antônio Beterraba 4
Maria Beterraba 3
José Cenoura 5
João Macarrão 21
João Molho de Tomate 1
```

**3.5 Quantos produtos diferentes foram vendidos por cada vendedor?**

Para contar quantos produtos diferentes foram vendidos por cada vendedor a função de agregação `COUNT` é a ideal

```
-- código #8
SELECT NomeVendedor, count (ProdutoVendido)
  from Vendas
  group by NomeVendedor;

Antonio 1
João 3
José 1
Maria 1
```

Ao consultar o resultado, e comparar com o conteúdo da tabela de `Vendas`, percebemos que para o Vendedor João foram contabilizados 3 produtos quando ele somente vendeu dois tipos de produtos: **Macarrão** e **Molho de tomate**. Mas ele fez duas vendas de macarrão. Como fazer para que a função de agregação `COUNT` somente some uma vez cada produto? A resposta está no uso de `DISTINCT`dentro do parâmetro da função, conforme

```
COUNT ( { [ [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression ] | * } )


-- código #8a
SELECT NomeVendedor, count (distinct ProdutoVendido)
  from Vendas
group by NomeVendedor;

Antonio 1
João 2
José 1
Maria 1
```

Agora sim o resultado veio correto, com o vendedor `João` contabilizando 2 produtos diferentes.

E como ficaram os planos de execução dos códigos #8 e #8a?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c0334/3/0)

Percebe-se em ambos a presença do operador `Stream Aggregate` devido à cláusula `GROUP BY`. E na segunda consulta, referente ao `código #8a` a presença do operador lógico `DISTINCT SORT`, antes de realizar o agrupamento. Este operador lógico foi incluído pelo otimizador de consultas para processar `DISTINCT ProdutoVendido`.

---

**4. GROUP BY no lugar de DISTINCT**

Quando a cláusula `GROUP BY` é utilizada sem que exista função de agregação na cláusula SELECT, ela possui efeito semelhante a de `DISTINCT`.

Por exemplo, o código #3a pode ser reescrito, substituindo DISTINCT por GROUP BY:

```
-- código #3a
SELECT DISTINCT NomeVendedor 
  from Vendas;


-- código #9
SELECT NomeVendedor
  from Vendas
  group by NomeVendedor;
```

O retorno do `código #9` é

```
Antônio
João
José
Maria
```

O plano de execução é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, o mesmo resultado e o mesmo plano de execução foram gerados para as duas consultas.

---

**5. Considerações parciais**

A pergunta deste tópico serviu de base para escrever artigo sobre o assunto. No item de referências ao final há o link para o artigo completo.

Neste texto a tabela `Vendas` é do tipo *heap* e sem índices *nonclustered*. Optou-se por esse tipo para demonstração do funcionamento conceitual de `GROUP BY` e `DISTINCT` pois a presença de índices pode alterar o plano de execução gerado.

`DISTINCT` e `GROUP BY` não fazem a mesma coisa, possuem objetivos diferentes e normalmente geram planos de execução diferentes.

***Há exceções.***

---

**6. Referências**

**6.1 Documentação**

- [Cláusula SELECT](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176104(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [Eliminando duplicatas com DISTINCT](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187831.aspx)
- [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [Funções de agregação](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173454(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [Sum()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql)
- [Count()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql)
- [Operador Stream Aggregate](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189907.aspx)
- [Operador Sort](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186318.aspx)

**6.2 Artigo completo**

- [DISTINCT x GROUP BY](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/09/02/distinct-x-group-by/)

---

Comment: Bem elaborada e explicativa a resposta

Comment: @RicardoPontual Quando li a sua resposta, votei nela e acrescentei comentário na pergunta. Mas como o autor solicitou algo mais detalhado, resolvi então escrever artigo a respeito, que breve será publicado. Parte do artigo foi transcrito para este tópico.

Comment: Ficou bom mesmo. Eu li bastante coisa mas não tinha achado nada completo em português

Comment: @JoséDiz a sua está mais explicado, já marquei como correta. Obrigado

Comment: Praticamente a primeira parte de uma monografia (+1)

Comment: Acrescentado o item 6.2, com link para o artigo completo.

Comment: Explicação excelente, me ajudou a entender

Answer (score 26):

São propostas bem diferentes. Enquanto `DISTINCT` visa trazer informações únicas, removendo duplicados, o `GROUP BY` agrupa os valores, e é usando em conjunto com as funções de agregação, como `COUNT`e `SUM`.

Seu exemplo não fez bom uso do `GROUP BY`, veja que não usa funções de agregação:

```
Select Nome, Sexo from Pessoa
Group by Nome, Sexo
```

Tente por exemplo contar quanto registros tem para cada sexo. A `query` abaixo faz isso de maneira bem simples:

```
select Sexo,Count(Sexo) from Pessoa
Group by Sexo
```

Agora tente fazer isso com o `DISTINCT`, a resposta é: não é possível.
Essa é diferença entre eles.

No caso do seu exemplo, como o objetivo é apenas obter os valores não duplicados, o `DISTINCT` é a melhor opção.

Quanto à performance, precisa ter uma boa massa de dados para fazer um benchmark e ver a diferença, mas acredito que, devido a funcionalidade, o `GROUP BY` para o seu exemplo não deve ser o mais recomendado.

**EDIT**: pesquisando, achei o seguinte link em inglês que afirma que ambos geram o mesmo plano de execução, mas é meio antigo, pode ser que algo tenha mudado para as versões mais atuais:  [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct#164485)

Comment: Além disso o GROUP by permite acesso a todos os registros omitidos, você pode usar funções de agregação como o `group_concat` por exemplo para concatenar todos os dados de um determinado campo omitidos no agrupamento.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho sim o `group_concat` ajuda, só lembrando que é uma função do **MySQL**, não me recordo de existir no **SQL Server** nem no **Oracle**

Comment: Verdade, no oracle a função similar é a `LISTAGG` (11g+)  que usa outro sistema de agrupamento. Acho que meu exemplo não foi o mais comum, talvez `SUM`  e `COUNT` sejam as mais universais.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho na vdd o `GROUP_CONCAT` também não funciona no MSSQL.

Comment: @RicardoPontual grato pela resposta, já deixei o meu +1.

Comment: Somente como informação complementar: está disponível a função string_agg() a partir da versão 2017 do SQL Server.

Answer (score 18):

Eles têm diferenças semânticas, mesmo que tenham resultados equivalentes em seus dados específicos.

`GROUP BY` permite usar funções agregadas, como `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, e `COUNT`. Outra mão `DISTINCT` simplesmente remove duplicatas.

Por exemplo, se você tiver um monte de registros de compras e quiser saber quanto gastou cada departamento, você pode fazer algo como:

```
SELECT departamento, SUM(valor) FROM compras GROUP BY departamento
```

Isso lhe dará uma linha por departamento, contendo o nome do departamento e a soma de todos os `valores` em todas as linhas para esse departamento.

No **SQL Server** não há diferença de performance, pois resultará no mesmo plano de execução.

"Um DISTINCT e GROUP BY geralmente geram o mesmo plano de consulta, de modo que o desempenho deve ser o mesmo em ambas as construções de consulta".

Fonte: [SQL Server Group by vs Distinct](http://Http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/distinct-vs-group), [Distinct vs Group By](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/)

No **Oracle** é a mesma situação, não há diferença.

Fonte: [DISTINCT vs, GROUP BY](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:32961403234212)

Pesquisando mais a fundo, encontrei um site onde mostra que dependendo da situação o `group by` torna-se mais performático do que o `distinct`, isso depende muito das `subquerys`.

Como há muita explicação, verifique no link:

[Surpresas de desempenho e premissas: GROUP BY vs. DISTINCT](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já deixei o meu +1.

Answer (score 13):

Uma resposta um pouco mais curta:

- `Distinct` é usado para filtrar registros exclusivos dos registros que satisfazem os critérios de consulta.

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT cliente FROM Pedidos;
  ```
- O `GROUP BY`é usada para agrupar os dados sobre os quais as funções de agregação(GROUP_CONCAT, COUNT, SUM por exemplo) são disparadas e a saída é retornada com base nas colunas da cláusula group by.

  ```
  SELECT
    cliente,
    count(*) as 'Total Pedidos',
    SUM(total_pedido) as 'Total em compras'

  FROM Pedidos GROUP BY cliente;
  ```

É difícil mensurar qual é mais rápido, se você quer valores únicos de uma determinada tabela o `DISTINCT` se mostrará mais performático, mas o que também não é uma regra absoluta. Dependendo dos índices e da forma com o SGBD implementa essa consulta a performance poderá variar.
Na maioria das vezes `GROUP BY` vai ser mais eficiente em operações que envolvam outras colunas além da que está sendo agrupada ou distinguida e não terá distinção do `DISTINCT` em operações de unicidade simples conforme mostrado nas outras respostas.

Comment: Leonan, já deixei meu +1, sua resposta está excelente. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

> Até onde sei (pelo menos seguindo os fundamentos de banco de dados e
>   não as implementações de cada fabricante), os algoritmos de DISTINCT e
>   GROUP BY são idênticos em suas fases iniciais seguindo primeiro uma
>   ordenação e posterior eliminação de repetições. A diferença entre os
>   algoritmos é que o GROUP BY permite funções de agregação como um passo
>   adicional enquanto que o DISTINCT não permite. Quando se utiliza o
>   GROUP BY sem essas funções, estaremos "repetindo" exatamente as fases
>   iniciais que o DISTINCT utiliza.

- [Duvida o que é melhor distinct ou group by](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/0dfe8066-da5c-4271-87d4-d4e0d8c173c6/duvida-o-que-melhor-distinct-ou-group-by?forum=transactsqlpt)

Comment: Foi você quem escreveu a resposta na MSDN?

Comment: Ao pegar um texto completo talvez seja interessante colocar como citação e referenciar o autor(link pelo menos) e quem sabe adicionar umas considerações pessoais.