# Tenho este cursor e o 'between' do where dá erro. Queria selecionar os anos de 2005 a 2008

Tags: sql-server, tsql, ssms

```
DECLARE @Year int
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
Select distinct Year(OrderDate) as Year
From Sales.SalesOrderHeader
Order by Year(OrderDate)

OPEN db_cursor FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Year
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN

--INSERT INTO xxxxx ("Year", "Month", "Total", "RunningTotal")
SELECT a.Year, a.Month, Sum(a.TotalDue) as Total, Sum(a.RunningTotal) as RunningTotal
From (
    select Year = Year(convert(int,OrderDate,111)),
        case Month(convert(int,OrderDate,111))
            when 1 then 'Janeiro'
            when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
            when 3 then 'Março'
            when 4 then 'Abril'
            when 5 then 'Maio'
            when 6 then 'Junho'
            when 7 then 'Julho'
            when 8 then 'Agosto'
            when 9 then 'Setembro'
            when 10 then 'Outubro'
            when 11 then 'Novembro'
            when 12 then 'Dezembro'
        else 'unknown'
        end as "Month1",
        Month = Month(convert(int,OrderDate,111)),
        TotalDue = convert(money,TotalDue,1),
        RunningTotal = convert(money,
            (SELECT sum(convert(money, TotalDue,1))
             FROM   Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Header
             WHERE  SalesOrderID <= soh.SalesOrderID
                AND year(OrderDate) '2005' between '2008'
                ),
            1)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
    WHERE year(OrderDate) '2005' between '2008'
) a
group by a.Year, a.Month
order by 1, 2;

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Year
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

--End Cursor
```

Comment: Remova o `distinct` do começo da query, acabei de fazer uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-n%C3%A3o-fazem-a-mesma-coisa) sobre `Group by e Distinct `juntos e acredito não haver um uso em que os dois são necessários. Não consigo entender o porque do `CONVERT`dentro da função `YEAR`, o mesmo para a Função `MONTH`(*Não poderia colocar a data direto dentro da função?*) São coisas simples, mas que ajudam no desempenho.

Comment: resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 2):

tá errada a sintaxe...

tem que ser

```
WHERE year(OrderDate) between '2005' and '2008'
```

Comment: a query não executa. Alguma ideia?

Comment: acontece algum erro ?

Comment: demorou 8 minutos a executar mas está bem

Comment: certo, sobre o tempo de demora, verifique os índices e se realmente é necessário a utilização de todas essas funções, com certeza você pode melhorar o desempenho

Answer (score 2):

Você tem dois erro de sintaxe que eu pude ver de cara, o primeiro é o uso do [BETWEEN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql)

```
AND year(OrderDate) '2005' between '2008'
```

O correto na sintaxe é

```
WHERE col BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

E seu outro erro e comparar o retorno do seu [YEAR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql) com um varchar, o year retorna um int então compare com um int.

O Correto seria

```
WHERE year(OrderDate) between 2005 and 2008
```

Algumas coisas na sua query são desnecessárias como `Month(convert(int,getdate(),111))` não há necessidade aqui de usar o convert quando você pode usar o Month para retorna o mês veja que o select abaixo retornar o mesmo resultado.

```
select Month(convert(int,getdate(),111)), Month(getdate())
```

O mesmo vale para o Year.

Não sei qual a ideia de usar o CURSOR ??  você fez ele e não usou para nada...

```
DECLARE @Year int
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
Select distinct Year(OrderDate) as Year
From Sales.SalesOrderHeader
Order by Year(OrderDate)

OPEN db_cursor FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Year
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

Se seu objetivo é fazer um insert com os dados de retorno baseado em um intervalo de ANOS (2005 - 2008) use um [lool for](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php) e evite de fazer um select sem necessidade.

```
DECLARE @ano INT = 2005;

WHILE @ano < 2009
BEGIN
   {-- todo}
   SET @ano = @ano + 1;
END;
```

Use a variável que você esta incrementado no seu loop para fazer o select

```
AND year(OrderDate) = @ano;
```

no lugar do seu  `AND year(OrderDate) '2005' between '2008'`

e por fim se só for fazer o insert nesse intervalo mesmo então use somente o between e retire de dentro do seu CURSOR ele só vai duplicar seu dados do jeito que esta.

Comment: Eu quero usar para arredondar o total e o runningtotal com 2 decimas. Como fazer? Quero também analisar os restantes anos

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seu erro seja mesmo de sintaxe; usa o *[between](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql)* como abaixo:

```
WHERE year(OrderDate) between '2005' and '2008'
```

OBS: repara que nas duas vezes que você usa o *between* o erro acontece, então corrige nos dois pontos.

Comment: a query fica muito tempo a correr...Obrigada pelo reparo:)

Comment: Como colocar duas casas décimais no Total e no RunningTotal com Cursores?

Comment: depende da versão do _sql_ que você usa. Tenta usar `PARSENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(1112 AS MONEY),1),2)`, caso não dê certo, procura algum compatível com o seu