# Dados sendo repetidos quando usando INNER JOIN no Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

Eu tenho três tabelas, que são as seguintes : `ALUNO`,`CLASSE` e `MATRICULA`.

**ALUNO**

```
 NR_RGM
 NM_NOME
 NM_PAI
 NM_MAE
 DT_NASCIMENTO
 ID_SEXO
```

**CLASSE**

```
CD_CLASSE
NR_ANOLETIVO
CD_ESCOLA
CD_GRAU
NR_SERIE
TURMA
CD_PERIODO
```

**MATRICULA**

```
CD_CLASSE
NR_RGM
DT_MATRICULA
```

Eu estou fazendo um `INNER JOIN` com as três tabelas para poder me retornar uma query. Sendo esta query :

```
select a.nm_nome
from aluno a
inner join matricula ma on (ma.nr_rgm = a.nr_rgm)
inner join classe c on (c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe)
where a.nm_nome LIKE '%SILAS%' AND c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe
```

A query funciona, mas o problema é que ela me retorna resultados repetidos. E aparece no Oracle pelos resultados o seguinte :

[image]

Como eu posso fazer somente me retorna os dados necessários sem serem repetidos ? Sei que já há algumas outras perguntas similares, mas elas não me ajudaram no que preciso.

Comment: Se quiser apenas trazer 1 registro de cada, faça um agrupamento pela PK, exemplo `group by a.nr_rgm `, o motivo de trazer varias linhas é que alguma tabela tem mais de 1 registro referenciando ao aluno/matricula

Comment: Sim eu consegui resolver aqui agora através do GROUP BY em que eu usei o nome ao invés da chave primária e deu certo, muito obrigado. Se quiser, você pode colocar como resposta e eu te darei como resposta certa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa agrupar os dados para retornar 1 registro de cada.

[group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) exemplo:

```
select a.nm_nome
  from aluno a
 inner join matricula ma on (ma.nr_rgm = a.nr_rgm)
 inner join classe c on (c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe)
 where a.nm_nome LIKE '%SILAS%' AND c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe
 group by a.nm_nome
```

Outra solução é usar [distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
select distinct a.nm_nome
  from aluno a
 inner join matricula ma on (ma.nr_rgm = a.nr_rgm)
 inner join classe c on (c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe)
 where a.nm_nome LIKE '%SILAS%' AND c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe
```

Relacionado: [DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228294/57801)

Você precisa analisar o seguinte: Vou ter 2 alunos com o mesmo nome? Se sim, agrupar apenas pelo nome não seria o ideal, você precisará colocar o `a.nr_rgm` no seu SELECT para separar ambos.

```
select a.nr_rgm, a.nm_nome
  from aluno a
 inner join matricula ma on (ma.nr_rgm = a.nr_rgm)
 inner join classe c on (c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe)
 where a.nm_nome LIKE '%SILAS%' AND c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe
 group by a.nr_rgm, a.nm_nome
```