# Trocar WHILE por GROUP em SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso de uma função SQL para obter dados agrupados por mês.
Tenho na coluna `CPCCodeID` códigos (ex: 512456). Eu preciso contar e agrupar pelos dois primeiros dígitos. Preciso disso separado por meses (!!!) e para tornar isso mais fácil fiz esse loop que passa por todos os meses e agrupa da maneira que eu preciso.

Neste momento cheguei a esta solução:

```
USE CCILCDatabase;  
GO  
DECLARE  @mes  int;  
SET  @mes  =  1;  
WHILE (select @mes) <= 12 
BEGIN  
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2), COUNT(*)
FROM PublicContestCPC
where YEAR(DateCreated) = '2017' AND MONTH(DateCreated) = (select @mes)
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2)
ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2)
SET @mes += 1;
END  
PRINT @mes;
```

Eu sei que dá para alterar este código para não usar o `loop`, mas o meu conhecimento de SQL é um pouco limitado. Eu queria usar isto para exportar para uma folha Excel, mas da maneira como está implementado não funciona.

Comment: Qual a necessidade disto? `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2)`. Poderia explicar melhor sua duvida, talvez consiga te ajudar!

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: [DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ambas-as-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

Comment: já adicionei mais detalhes do que pretendo fazer.

Comment: Só isso resolveria o problema? `SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2), COUNT(*)
FROM PublicContestCPC
where YEAR(DateCreated) = '2017' AND MONTH(DateCreated) <=@mes
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2)
ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2)`

Comment: isso dá-me os resultados que eu quero, mas é só de um mês

Comment: coloca o mês no resultado: `SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2), mes, COUNT(*) FROM PublicContestCPC where YEAR(DateCreated) = '2017' AND MONTH(DateCreated) <=@mes GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2),mes ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPCCodeID]),2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Eu preciso contar e agrupar pelos dois primeiros dígitos. Preciso disso separado por meses*...

Avalie

```
-- código #1 v2
USE CCILCDatabase;  
go

SELECT month(DateCreated) as Mes,
       convert(char(2), CPCCodeID) as Alg2, 
       count(*) as Estat

  from PublicContestCPC

  where DateCreated between '20170101' and '20171231'

  group by month(DateCreated), convert(char(2), CPCCodeID)

  order by Mes, Alg2;
```

O código acima considera que a coluna `DateCreated` é do tipo *date* e que a coluna `CPCCodeId` possui ao menos 2 algarismos.