# Adicionar o SUM() nos resultados da querry

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho esta querry que me dá o nr total de linhas que começam com o mesmo código

```
USE CCILCDatabase;  
GO  
DECLARE  @mes  int;  
SET  @mes  =  1;  
WHILE (select @mes) <= 12 
BEGIN  
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPVCodeID]),2), COUNT(*)
FROM PublicContestCPV
where YEAR(DateCreated) = '2016' AND MONTH(DateCreated) = (select @mes) AND (PublicContestID in (SELECT ContestID FROM PublicContests where [UEPublicContestType] = ''))
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPVCodeID]),2)
ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPVCodeID]),2)
SET @mes += 1;
END  
PRINT @mes;
```

Eu precisava, para além da contagem, que mostrasse também o `SUM()` de uma coluna (**ContractValue**) que está na tabela **PublicContests**. O meu SQL não está muito treinado, e essa querry que preciso parece-me impossível.

Comment: Veja se minha resposta te atende, para ser mais preciso eu precisaria das colunas que ralacionam as duas tabelas.

Comment: Vide https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272917/trocar-while-por-group-em-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer a soma do valor, relacionei as duas tabelas através de um `LEFT JOIN` e busquei `SUM(ContractValue)`:

```
DECLARE  @mes  int;  
SET  @mes  =  1;  
WHILE (select @mes) <= 12 
BEGIN  

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPVCodeID]),2) [Codigo]
    , COUNT(*) [Quantidade]
    , SUM(ContractValue) [Valor]
FROM PublicContestCPV
LEFT JOIN PublicContests
    ON PublicContestCPV.PublicContestID = PublicContests.PublicContestID
    AND UEPublicContestType = ''
WHERE YEAR(DateCreated) = '2016' 
    AND MONTH(DateCreated) = (select @mes)
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPVCodeID]),2)
ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CPVCodeID]),2)

SET @mes += 1;
END  
PRINT @mes;
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso agrupar pelo código CPVCodeID, pode modificar isso para estar com o loop, mas mostrar também o SUM()? Assim eu tenho no output 12 tabelas, depois é só copiar e colar cada mês

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: funcionou 5* :)

Answer (score 1):

Eis o código proposto no tópico [Trocar WHILE por GROUP em SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272917/trocar-while-por-group-em-sql) (muito semelhante a este e ambos de sua autoria), modificado para acrescentar o somatório:

```
-- código #1 v2
USE CCILCDatabase;  
go

SELECT month(DateCreated) as Mes,
       convert(char(2), CPCCodeID) as Alg2, 
       count(*) as Qtd,
       sum(Contractvalue) as Soma

  from PublicContestCPV

  where DateCreated between '20160101' and '20161231'
        and PublicContestID in (SELECT ContestID 
                                  from PublicContests
                                  where UEPublicContestType = '')

  group by month(DateCreated), convert(char(2), CPCCodeID)

  order by Mes, Alg2;
```

É bem mais eficiente utilizar a cláusula GROUP BY do que o loop por WHILE. Ao utilizar o loop, os dados são lidos 12 vezes enquanto que com a cláusula GROUP BY os dados são lidos uma única vez.

---

(1) Para acessar o conteúdo da variável `@mes` não é necessário utilizar a construção `(select @mes)`. Basta utilizar `@mes`. Por exemplo:

```
WHILE @mes <= 12
```

(2) Construções do tipo `where YEAR(DateCreated) = '2016'` podem ser ineficientes, caso exista índice de cobertura pela coluna `DateCreated`. Pesquise por *sargable*.

Comment: acredito que a necessidade dele era outra, visto que em comentário ele me pediu para manter o while.

Comment: isso também está certo, mas a resposta acima era mais adequada, como o @CaiqueRomero mencionou também.