# Como somar todos os valores de uma coluna no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Como faço para somar todos os pontos dos usuários? Por exemplo:

```
ID | NOME  |  PONTOS
 1 | Joao  |   100
 2 | Bia   |    50
```

Sabe-se que a soma de todos os pontos do banco de dados é 150.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(PONTOS) AS total FROM tabela;`

Comment: obgd, irei testar

Answer (score 10):

#### Como fazer

Somando geral:

```
SELECT SUM(PONTOS) AS total 
FROM tabela
```

Somando por usuários:

```
SELECT NOME, SUM(PONTOS) AS total 
FROM tabela
GROUP BY NOME
```

Contando a quantidade de registros por usuário:

```
SELECT NOME, COUNT(PONTOS) AS registros
FROM tabela
GROUP BY NOME
```

Exibindo a média por usuário:

```
SELECT NOME, AVG(PONTOS) AS media
FROM tabela
GROUP BY NOME
```

Todos acima juntos:

```
SELECT NOME, SUM(PONTOS) AS total, COUNT(PONTOS) AS registros, AVG(PONTOS) AS media
FROM tabela
GROUP BY NOME
```

---

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b53a54/2)

---

#### Referências

[COUNT, SUM, AVG](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

[GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

[DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/229072/92908)