# LIKE com COUNT em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Não consigo entender o que está dando de errado no código:

```
$query="SELECT aluno FROM bonesmirn2 WHERE data LIKE '%2018-09%' AS faltas  GROUP BY aluno HAVING COUNT(aluno) > 0 ORDER BY COUNT(aluno) DESC";


$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$response = array();

if($number_of_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $response[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode(array("lista"=>$response));
mysqli_close($dbcon);
```

Comment: qual é o problema?

Comment: Esse `LIKE` na data funciona como o esperado? Raramente vejo condições com datas feitas dessa forma.

Comment: O LIKE no "data" realmente funciona xD kkk mas optei pela a ideia do nosso amigo ae..mais abaixo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E esse `AS faltas` não significa nada, pois está dando apelido para um campo de filtro.

Usar `LIKE` para data, é uma "gambiarra", e que dá mais trabalho do que fazer certo.

---

#### Como trabalhar nas datas

Utilize as funções `YEAR, MONTH, DAY` para buscar o valor do **ANO, MÊS, DIA**  do campo `data`:

```
SELECT aluno FROM bonesmirn2 
WHERE YEAR(data) = '2018' AND MONTH(data) = '09'
```

Caso tenha **mais de 1** valor:

```
SELECT aluno FROM bonesmirn2 
WHERE YEAR(data) = '2018' AND MONTH(data) IN ('07','09','11')
```

Caso queira um **intervalo** sequencial:

```
SELECT aluno FROM bonesmirn2 
WHERE YEAR(data) = '2018' AND MONTH(data) BETWEEN '05' AND '12'
```

---

#### Como usar o `count`

Você precisa ter algo para "contar".
Mesmo que essa tabela tenha somente 1 registro de cada aluno, a contagem sempre será maior que 1, então é nula sua *query* com `HAVING COUNT(aluno) > 0`.

**Exemplo**

Você poderia contar quantas vezes o aluno aparece na tabela, assim criar um parâmetro.

Por exemplo, se essa tabela `bonesmirn2` é um registro de presença, vamos trazer somente os alunos que tiveram mais que 5 presença:

```
SELECT aluno, COUNT(aluno) as presenca
FROM bonesmirn2 
WHERE YEAR(data) = '2018' AND MONTH(data) = '09'  
GROUP BY aluno
HAVING COUNT(aluno) > 5 
ORDER BY COUNT(aluno) DESC
```

---

#### Links úteis

[Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

[DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ambas-as-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

[SQL HAVING Clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: No meu caso realmente e preciso deixar o "Having count ( ) > 0 " pois e uma tabela de faltas..então teria real que ser 0, concordo sr, era uma baita de uma gambiarra kkk, Funcionou perfeito aqui, vlw