# SQL utilizando sum

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
|  Data  |Quantidade|QTCxVer|QTCxBra|
|04.09.18|   10     |   1   |       |
|04.09.18|   30     |       |   3   |
|04.09.18|   40     |       |   4   |
|04.09.18|   50     |   5   |       |
|05.09.18|   20     |   2   |       |
|05.09.18|   10     |       |   1   |
|05.09.18|   30     |   3   |       |
```

Quero ter o seguinte resultado:

```
|  Data  |TotalVer|TotalBra|
|04.09.18|   60   |  70    |
|05.09.18|   50   |  10    |
```

Estou tentando da seguinte forma, mas está dando erro:

```
select
case when QTCxVer <> 0 then
  sum(Quantidade) as "TotalVer"
else
  sum(Quantidade) as "TotalBran"
end
from tb_teste
 group by  data
```

Comment: qual erro? ah, não faltou "data" no select?

Comment: você precisa de somar as duas colunas...e não só uma em um case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Corrigindo

A falha está na forma que está utilizando o `CASE`.

Como fazer:

```
SELECT data,
SUM(CASE WHEN QTCxVer <> 0 THEN Quantidade END) as TotalVer,
SUM(CASE WHEN QTCxBra <> 0 THEN Quantidade END) as TotalBran
FROM tb_teste
GROUP BY data
```

---

#### Links úteis

[DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ambas-as-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

---

#### Veja funcionando

- [SQLFiddle - MYSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5be049/4)
- [SQLFiddle - POSTGRE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c6727/1)

Comment: acho que colocaria um `else 0 end` se a coluna for null não vai somar

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Certeza? vou testar, perai

Comment: certeza não pelo SGDB, mas no postgresql, se uma linha for null a soma retorna null

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Postei o teste, normal nos 2! Dá uma olhada!

Comment: @rbz, _"Sempre que utiliza o GROUP BY, é necessário trazer o campo em questão."_ acho que o termo correto não seria "necessário", já que é possível usar `group by` omitindo do `select` o campo de agrupamento (não dá erro, apenas fica "difícil" saber à quê aquela quantidade - no caso desta pergunta - está relacionada); acho que ficaria melhor algo do tipo "Sempre que utiliza o GROUP BY, é _aconselhável_ trazer o campo em questão."

Comment: Concordo @rLinhares!

Answer (score -1):

```
select
    data,
    sum(quantidade * case when qtdcxver is not null and qtdcxver <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalVer,
    sum(quantidade * case when qtdcxbra is not null and qtdcxbra <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalBra
from tb_teste
group by data
```