# Ajuda com select complexo com dados da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenha uma tabela de lançamentos, onde tem dados tanto do credito, como da conta a receber, numa mesma tabela. Ao quitar uma conta a receber, isso gera um novo lançamento na mesma tabela, com outra operacao... o ponto é que quero fazer um select, que na conta original, traga o valor pago, buscando por todos os pagamentos, que referenciam a id da conta original.

```
SELECT 
"id", "valor",
 (SELECT SUM("valor") FROM "lancamentos" AS "L2" WHERE "status" = 1 AND "L2"."quitacaoid" = "lancamentos"."id")  as "valorquitado",
"emissao",
"lancamentos".*
 FROM 
"lancamentos"
WHERE 
 "lancamentos"."status" = 1 
 AND "lancamentos"."pessoaid" = '42b0592544814e84b07142f3354c656d'
 
 
 /* SOLUCAO DESEJADA, COMPRANDO O VALOR QUITADO PELO SUBSELECT ACIMA */

 AND (
 ("valorquitado" < "valor") 
 AND ("operacao" = 2) 
 )
 
 
 
 /* SOLUCAO COMENDADA FUNCIONA, QUE FAZ O MESMO EFEITO, MAS FAZ UM NOVO SUBSELECT
  AND (
 ((SELECT SUM("valor") FROM "lancamentos" AS "L2" WHERE "status" = 1 AND "L2"."quitacaoid" = "lancamentos"."id") < "valor") 
 AND ("operacao" = 2) 
 )
 */
 
 ORDER BY "lancamentos"."emissao" ASC
```

Essa solução comentada, traz o resultado desejado, mas minha pergunta é se há algo mais "performático" para trazer o mesmo resultado, sendo que estou fazendo um subselect em cada linha, e pior, 2 vezes.

Comment: Pouco claro para mim mas tente com CASE ... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328800/sql-utilizando-sum

Comment: não deu pra entender bem o que quer fazer, sugiro editar a pergunta, colocar o modelo da tabela, um exemplo dos dados relevantes o resultado que pretende

Comment: Só tem 1 tabela: lancamentos.

Colunas relevantes:
id, valor, quitacaoid

Dado1: id = 25, valor: 200, quitacaoid=''
Dado2: id = 26, valor: 150, quitacaoid='25'

Quero a lista com todas os lançamentos, sendo que a primeira, deve contar o valor de R$ 150,00 pago em uma coluna "valorquitado"

Comment: Edite a pergunta acrescentando os detalhes que você colocou no comentário. Veja se lhe atende: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17c068/3

Comment: a coluna `quitacaoid` dá-se a entender que é o id do pagamento, sendo uma relação de um pagamento para várias contas, quando na verdade é contrário... uma conta recebe vários pagamentos.

Comment: Existe campo "id", este é o id do pagamento si, o id do crédito. e o campo "quitacaoid". Este campo traz o id do lançamento orginal que gerou aquele crédito.

Comment: olhou o fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
SELECT 
    DADOSLANCAMENTOS.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        valor,
        (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos AS L2 WHERE status = 1 AND L2.quitacaoid = lancamentos.id)  as valorquitado,
        emissao,
        lancamentos.*
    FROM lancamentos
    WHERE lancamentos.status = 1 
        AND lancamentos.pessoaid = '42b0592544814e84b07142f3354c656d'    
) AS DADOSLANCAMENTOS
WHERE DADOSLANCAMENTOS.VALORQUITADO < DADOSLANCAMENTOS.VALOR AND DADOSLANCAMENTOS.OPERACAO = 2
ORDER BY DADOSLANCAMENTOS.emissao ASC
```

é mais performatico derivar esse seu primeiro select e utilizar os dados dele em um novo "nivel", assim evita de reescrever a subselect e executar ela duas vezes. A ideia dessa derivada é trazer os dados do seu primeiro select como se fosse uma tabela, assim, está sendo nomeada como 'DADOSLANCAMENTOS' e torna seu select bem mais performatico.

Comment: Tentei, mas não consegui rodar, apresentou o seguinte erro
column id was specified multiple times for derived table DADOSLANCAMENTOS

Comment: Oh, perdão não notei que estavam sendo listado todos os campos, essa mensagem se dá devido a estar sendo declarado duas vezes a coluna ID, uma vez na linha 5 e após na llinha 9, devido a estar sendo listado todos os campos da tabela lancamentos, isso vai ocorrer para todos os campos repetidos, para resolver isso voce pode tirar exibição dos campos (id,  valor, emissao) ou listar apenas os campos necessarios ao invez de todos da tabela como está sendo feito pelo 'lancamentos.*'.