# Somar valores de um select quando repetir o id cliente

Tags: php, mysqli

Como eu poderia somar os valores de um select quando repete o id do cliente?

**Exemplo**

Uso esse select:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row["nome"]. " - " . $row["valor"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

**Resultado:**

> Manoel - R$20,00
>
> Manoel - R$40,00
>
> Isac- R$60,00
>
> Isac- R$40,00
>
> João- R$40,00

**Como eu preciso que fique somando os valores sem repetir os nomes dos clientes:**

> Manoel - R$60,00
>
> Isac- R$100,00
>
> João- R$40,00

Comment: Leia sobre o `group by` do SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) do SQL.

Para o resultado que você quer a *query* seria:

```
SELECT nome, SUM(valor) valor FROM clientes GROUP BY nome
```

Answer (score 2):

Agrupe o resultado pelo *nome do usuário* utilizando a cláusula `GROUP BY` e utilize a função `SUM` para somar esses resultados agrupados.

Modifique sua query para ficar na seguinte forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT nome, SUM(valor) FROM clientes GROUP BY nome";
```

No link que estou deixando abaixo tem uma resposta bem completa de como funciona essa cláusula `GROUP BY` do SQL.

Link: [DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ambas-as-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es/229072)