# Query SQL Somar valor duplicado

Tags: sql

Ao executar a query SQL recebo o seguinte resultado;
[image: Resultado da execução da query]

Porem, gostaria de receber o resultado da seguinte forma;

[image: 886992532299]

Query SQL executada;

```
SELECT

        CODIGO_BARRAS.barra,
        produtos_eventos.quantidade


     FROM
        PRODUTOS_EVENTOS,
        MOVIMENTO, 
        CODIGO_BARRAS
     WHERE
         MOVIMENTO.COD_OPERACAO = PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COD_OPERACAO
        and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.PRODUTO = CODIGO_BARRAS.PRODUTO
        and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COR = CODIGO_BARRAS.COR
        and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.TAMANHO = CODIGO_BARRAS.TAMANHO
        and   PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.NOTA='2949'
        and MOVIMENTO.DATA_ATUALIZACAO >'01.12.2018'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eis sugestão em que na cláusula FROM ficam as junções e na cláusula WHERE os filtros.

```
-- código #1
set dateformat dmy;
SELECT CODIGO_BARRAS.barra,
       sum (produtos_eventos.quantidade) as Quantidade
  from PRODUTOS_EVENTOS
       inner join MOVIMENTO on MOVIMENTO.COD_OPERACAO = PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COD_OPERACAO 
       inner join CODIGO_BARRAS on PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.PRODUTO = CODIGO_BARRAS.PRODUTO
                                   and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COR = CODIGO_BARRAS.COR
                                   and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.TAMANHO = CODIGO_BARRAS.TAMANHO
  where PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.NOTA='2949'
        and MOVIMENTO.DATA_ATUALIZACAO >'01.12.2018'
  group by CODIGO_BARRAS.barra;
```

Answer (score 4):

Agrupe o resultado pelo código de barras utilizando a cláusula `GROUP BY` e utilize a função de agregação `SUM()` para somar esses resultados agrupados.

Modifique sua query para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT CODIGO_BARRAS.barra,
       SUM(produtos_eventos.quantidade) AS Quantidade
 FROM
    PRODUTOS_EVENTOS,
    MOVIMENTO, 
    CODIGO_BARRAS
 WHERE
     MOVIMENTO.COD_OPERACAO = PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COD_OPERACAO
    and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.PRODUTO = CODIGO_BARRAS.PRODUTO
    and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COR = CODIGO_BARRAS.COR
    and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.TAMANHO = CODIGO_BARRAS.TAMANHO
    and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.NOTA='2949'
    and MOVIMENTO.DATA_ATUALIZACAO >'01.12.2018'
GROUP BY CODIGO_BARRAS.barra
```

No link que estou deixando abaixo tem uma resposta bem completa de como funciona essa cláusula GROUP BY do SQL.

Link: [DISTINCT e GROUP BY, qual a diferença entre ambas as declarações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ambas-as-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

Comment: Boa, estava criando a resposta! +1

Comment: Valeu amigo, se tiver algo para complementar manda bala!

Comment: Paulo, a única coisa que alteraria seria o alias 'as' após o sum, para que seja exibida a coluna igualmente 'quantidade'

Comment: Boa observação, alterada a resposta!!

Comment: Show cara, agora está completo.

Comment: Agora ficou perfeito!

Answer (score 2):

Olá! Você pode utilizar a function SUM(), agrupando pela coluna Codigo_Barras.barra. Segue:

```
SELECT
      CODIGO_BARRAS.barra,
      SUM(produtos_eventos.quantidade) AS QUANTIDADE
  FROM
      PRODUTOS_EVENTOS,
      MOVIMENTO, 
      CODIGO_BARRAS
  WHERE
      MOVIMENTO.COD_OPERACAO = PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COD_OPERACAO
      and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.PRODUTO = CODIGO_BARRAS.PRODUTO
      and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.COR = CODIGO_BARRAS.COR
      and PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.TAMANHO = CODIGO_BARRAS.TAMANHO
      and   PRODUTOS_EVENTOS.NOTA='2949'
      and MOVIMENTO.DATA_ATUALIZACAO >'01.12.2018'
      GROUP BY CODIGO_BARRAS.barra
```